Unable to test Strapi endpoints using Jest as always get 403 forbidden even when logged in or all routes are set to public
I have followed the instructions in Strapi's documentation to write unit tests using Jest. An instance of Strapi is created and I have added data to a temporary database. However, I can't seem to access routes to test them as I get 403 forbidden. I have found some help online to try and set all routes to allow public access and have also tried created an authenticated user. Neither have been successful.
This is the startup function that creates a Strapi instance, adds data and attempts to make all routes publicly accessible.
async function setupStrapi() {
  if (!instance) {
    await Strapi().load();
    instance = strapi;
   
    await instance.server.mount();
  }

  // build tables and relations
  ...

//   set all routes to public access
  const roles = await strapi
  .service("plugin::users-permissions.role")
  .find();


const _public = await strapi
  .service("plugin::users-permissions.role")
  .findOne(roles.filter((role) => role.type === "public")[0].id);

  const _auth = await strapi
  .service("plugin::users-permissions.role")
  .findOne(roles.filter((role) => role.type === "authenticated")[0].id);

  Object.keys(_public.permissions)
    .filter(permission => permission.startsWith('api'))
    .forEach(permission => {
      
        const controller = Object.keys(
            _public.permissions[permission].controllers
          )[0];
    
          setAllEndpointsToEnableTrue(
            _public.permissions[permission].controllers[controller]
          );
         
    });
    Object.keys(_auth.permissions)
    .filter(permission => permission.startsWith('api'))
    .forEach(permission => {
      
        const controller = Object.keys(
            _auth.permissions[permission].controllers
          )[0];
    
          setAllEndpointsToEnableTrue(
            _auth.permissions[permission].controllers[controller]
          );
         
    });

   

  return instance;

}

function setAllEndpointsToEnableTrue(obj) {
  for (let key in obj) {
    if (obj[key] && typeof obj[key] === "object" && "enabled" in obj[key]) {
      obj[key].enabled = true;
    }
 
  }
}

And this is an example of a test (I have tried similar setups with other routes):
const fs = require('fs');
const { setupStrapi, cleanupStrapi } = require("./helpers/strapi");
const request = require('supertest');
const forimages = require('src/api/kidney-score/controllers/kidney-score/filterImages');


jest.setTimeout(15000)


beforeAll(async () => {
  await setupStrapi();

 });

afterAll(async () => {
  await cleanupStrapi();
});

it("should return correct scores for images that have been scored multiple or no times", async () => {
    
    
    const response = await request(strapi.server.httpServer)
    .get("/api/kidney-scores/forimages")
    .send({images: [1, 2]})
    .expect(200) // Expect response http code 200
    .then((data) => {
        expect(data.body.length).toBe(2)
        expect(data.body).toInclude(scores.data[0])
        expect(data.body).toInclude(scores.data[1])
        expect(data.body).not.toInclude(scores.data[2])
    
      });

});

